# Streamlit Python uploaded files

Tags: python, streamlit

Help.I'm new to a Streamlit and the following code was taken from my `app.py`. I ran `streamlit run app.py` so a new browser would popup and displaying Streamlit App.

```
from be_app import * 

print_heading("Welcome to PDF Merger")
print_text("The purpose of this system is to merge bulk pdf at once.")

print_heading("How does it work?",2)
print_text("Basically the system will read all of your pdf files, then merge them based on their name.")
print_text("* 1FA02252303353CERT-030.pdf will be merged with 1FA02252303353KLSLCERT-030.pdf")
print_text("* 1FA02252303353CERT-031.pdf will be merged with 1FA02252303353KLSLCERT-031.pdf")
print_text("and so on.")
print_heading("Let's give it a try:",4)
print_heading("1. Upload files",1,10)
uploaded_files = print_uploader(prompt="Upload all PDFS here:"
                                ,on_change=post_uploaded_file(uploaded_files)
                                ,arr_extensions=['pdf']
                                ,accept_multiple_files=True
                                )
print_heading("2. Hit the button below!")
print_button("3. Merge files!",on_click=merge_files(),button_type='secondary')
```

I have question in handling uploading files. As we can see from `app.py` above, the `print_uploader` executing the following function:

```
folder_uploaded_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"streamlit_input_folder")

def post_uploaded_file(uploaded_files,folder_to_store=folder_uploaded_file):
     save_uploaded_file(uploaded_files=uploaded_files,folder_to_store=folder_to_store)
```

which execute the following functions:

```
def save_uploaded_file(uploaded_files,folder_to_store):
    for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
        with open(os.path.join(folder_to_store,uploaded_file.name),"wb") as f:
            f.write(uploaded_file.getbuffer())
            f.close()
```

question:

how do I refer the following `uploaded_files` as 1 variable?

```
uploaded_files = print_uploader(prompt="Upload all PDFS here:"
                                ,on_change=post_uploaded_file(uploaded_files)
                                ,arr_extensions=['pdf']
                                ,accept_multiple_files=True
                                )
```

Comment: Have you tried to save them in the [session_state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) ? Like: st.session_state["uploaded_files"] .

Comment: thanks @matleg finally that really helps